# Copy file to a path with Cordova Hybrid app

Tags: javascript, android, performance, cordova, sapui5

**Context**: I am developing hybrid app with Cordova 6 and SAPUI5 Framework (for now only need to worry about Android).

**What I want**: Copy/move a file to a path fast. Maybe getting a [FileEntry](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.0.0/cordova/file/fileentry/fileentry.html) from a File/Blob object from a [FileUploader](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader/constructor) on sapui5.

**Input**: [FileUploader](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader/constructor)

**Output**: File Object
So I get the file when I select it by doing the following:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId('file-uploader-id').oFileUpload.files[0];
```

So then I have to copy it to another location: "[cordova.file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/8.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#android-file-system-layout).externalCacheDirectory". But FileUploader doesn't provide a fullpath value for the selected item ([for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)).

**What I tried**:

```
        var sPath = URL.createObjectURL(oFile);
        var pCopyFrom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(sPath, resolve, reject);
        });

        var pCopyTo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var sExternalCachePath = cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory;
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(sMediaPath, resolve, reject);
        });

        Promise.all([pCopyFrom, pCopyTo]).then(aValues => {
            aValues[0].moveTo(aValues[1], aValues[0].name, cbSuccess, cbError);
        });
```

**Result**:

Solution seems to don't work because the generated path is not available (error code 5), this path is not valid for use it like this.

**Possible solutions**:

- Extract the path of the file object by another way.
- Use another input that can provide this path (until now I did not find any).
- Find the path of the file using the filename or maybe the size or something recursively at the phone.

**What is the current solution (But really slow)**:

Write the file with [FileWritter](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/3.1.0/cordova/file/filewriter/filewriter.html). If I have the path and I use the above code to a video (of 5 seconds of duration) it spends **less than 1 second** (thanks to [FileEntry](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.0.0/cordova/file/fileentry/fileentry.html#moveto)) to copy/move it (using a camera capture or video capture with [cordova-plugin-media-capture](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/) that gives the path of the file), while using [FileWritter](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/3.1.0/cordova/file/filewriter/filewriter.html) method it spends **like 10 seconds** to write it.

Thank you by reading. I will upload any new as I have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution is the second option that I said on the question, changing the input method:

Instead of using the [FileUploader](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader/constructor) as input, use a plugin called [File Selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-selector).

You can get the FileName, **URI**, Mime type and the file extension

So now I can move/copy the file faster with the [FileEntry](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.0.0/cordova/file/fileentry/fileentry.html#moveto).

Anyway I will update this answer if I find something relevant to this theme.

Thanks.